# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'train'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am getting a answer that 'tuple' object has no attribute 'train'. I can not understand this error(I am using google colab). Please, help me, and explain more detail (training part) as you can. my code is in the below. Thanks a lot in advance

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

## loading nessecery functions and CIFAR10 dataset 

from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

tf.__version__

((train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y)) = cifar10.load_data()
print(f"train_X: {train_X.shape}, test_X = {test_X.shape}")

cifar10 = cifar10.load_data()

# define placeholder for inputs to network
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3072])/255.0   # 32x32x3
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs =10
batch_size = 30

# weights & bias for nn layers
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3072, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))
hypothesis = tf.matmul(X, W) + b

# define cost/loss & optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=hypothesis, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# initialize
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# train my model
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
   avg_cost = 0
   num_examples = 50000
   total_batch = int(num_examples / batch_size)
```

My question is here

```
 for i in range(total_batch):
       batch_xs, batch_ys = cifar10.train.next_batch(batch_size)
       feed_dict = {X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys}
       c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
       avg_cost += c / total_batch

   print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch + 1), 'cost =', '{:.9f}'.format(avg_cost))

print('Learning Finished!')



# Test model and check accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print('Accuracy:', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: cifar10.test.images, Y: cifar10.test.labels}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a `train` attribute from a tuple resulting from `cifar10.load_data()`. You've already loaded the data correctly on a previous step:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
```

`cifar10.load_data()` is a data loader, which returns the train and test sets of the dataset.

If you want to implement a `next_batch` method to do as above, you'll need to define a custom helper class, which is something quite commonly used. Here's an [example case](https://www.kaggle.com/avis1102/cnn-with-cifar).